# Selecting first item in a subquery of many to many relationship in django

Tags: django

Consider having a `Book` model with many `Comment`s (from different `User`s) which may belong to many `Categories`.

```
class Category(Model):
  title = CharField(max_length=200)

class Book(Model):
  title = CharField(max_length=200)
  categories = ManyToManyField(Category)

class User(Model):
  name = CharField(max_length=200)

class Comment(Book):
  content = TextField()
  book = ForeignKey(Book, null=False, on_delete=CASCADE)
  user = ForeignKey(User, null=False, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

I want to select comments for an specific `Book`, and for each `Comment`, annotate it with the number of comments that the writer of that `Comment` wrote for the first `Category` of that book. And I want to this in a single query. Something like this:

```
def get_commnets(book):
  
  main_category = book.categories.first()

  n_same_comments_subquery = Subquery(
    Comments.objects
    .filter(user__id=OuterRef('user_id'), book__category__first=main_category)
    .annotate(count=Count('pk'))
    .values('count')
    )[:1]

  comments = (
    book.comment_set
    .annotate(n_same_comments=n_same_comments_subquery)
  )

  return comments
```

The previous piece of code does not work, obviously. This is because there is not any lookup like `first`. I've tried many other solutions, but non of them worked.

How can I achieve this goal?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to use `through`:

```
def get_commnets(book):
  
  main_category_id = book.categories.first().id

  n_same_comments_subquery = Subquery(
    Comments.objects
    .alias(first_book_category_id=Book.categories.through.objects.filter(book_id=OuterRef('book_id')).values('id')[:1])
    .filter(user__id=OuterRef('user_id'), first_book_category_id=main_category_id)
    .annotate(count=Count('pk'))
    .values('count')[:1]
    )

  comments = (
    book.comment_set
    .annotate(n_same_comments=n_same_comments_subquery)
  )

  return comments
```